# Запретить поворот Activity и всего приложения

Tags: java, android, activity, view

Добрый день.

Как правильно решить такую ситуацию?

Есть андроид-приложение, которое зависит от одного параметра - диагональ дисплея. Эту величину, или приблизительную к ней, я нахожу - проблем нету. 
В зависимости от дисплея >5 дюймов - только landscape, <5 - только портрет.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (ScreenSize<5) {
            setContentView(R.layout.startactivity_p); //отобразить хмл портретный
        }
        else{
            setContentView(R.layout.startactivity_l); // отобразить хмл ландскейп
        }

    }
```

В каждом xml-layout'е прописал следующее:

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
android:orientation="vertical"
```

и

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:orientation="horizontal"
```

соответственно.

Но приложение все равно поворачивается. Подскажите, как можно это исправить?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Для каждого вашего случая

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

и

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

Не поворачивается. Вообще вот хорошая [статья](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/orientation.php).

Answer (score 13):

Всё  же  лучше в Манифесте  это сделать.

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

или

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

Всё вместе:

```
<activity android:name=".SomeActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```