# Блокировка поворота экрана

Tags: android, android-studio, экран

Как сделать блокировка поворота экрана в приложении​ ?
Не работает :

```
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:orientation="lock"
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Запретить поворот Activity и всего приложения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/379391/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d1%82-activity-%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы неправильно указываете атрибуты, да и непонятно где, но догадываюсь, что в xml layout.

Правильно это делать в `AndroidManifest.xml`, указывайте нужную ориентацию для каждой `activity`

```
    <activity 
             android:name=".YourActivity"
             android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

Comment: Спасибо за верный ответ