# Android Как запретить приложению открываться в портретном режиме

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rotation

Мне нужно было запретить моему Kotlin приложению на андроид менять ориентацию (экрана).Код приложенный  [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/379391/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82-activity-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)  не работает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Все попытки гуглежа упирались в аналогичные ответы.

Так - же IDE предложила использовать `tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity">`. Но приложение всё равно продолжает вращаться. Можете подсказать в чём дело.

Comment: Так у вас написано `portrait`. Замените на `landscape` и будет **активность** открываться горизонтально

Comment: Оно всё равно меняет. У меня написано `portrait`, я вращаю телефоном, а оно то `portrait` , то `landscape`.

Comment: `tools:ignore` это только для IDE, на само приложение не влияет. Возможно вы в манифесте устанавливаете одной активити, а запускаете другую.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В манифесте установите это для всех ваших активити:

```
<activity_android:name =".YourActivity"     
android:configChanges="orientation" 
android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть вариант задать это программно:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

Comment: У меня пишет `Unresolved reference: setRequestedOrientation Alt+Shift+Enter Alt+Enter`

Comment: @BlueScreen вы это делаете в OnCreate в активити?

Comment: Я попробовал в `OnCreate` `OnViewCreated` `onCreateView`, не в одном не сработало. К счастью метод [Sergei Buvaka](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/288062/sergei-buvaka) сработал.